# table generation runtime

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jinternalframe

Hello to all Stackoverflow developers thanks for helping me .
I am working on a swing project .In which , i have to add a jinternal frame on jframe . i am adding the jinternal frame by calling method

```
Container.add(jinternalframe1);
```

the internalframe is being added but its moving , i want to disable the movement of the jinternalframe. on clicking a button on jinternalframe i want to add a JList and JTable on the previous frame window

I am calling the method

```
frame1.cp.add(list1);
frame1.cp.add(table1);
```

while clicking on jlist the table should be removed and new table should be generated. I am writing the following code for it

```
ms.cp.remove(table);
table= new JTable(String title, Object obj[][]);
add(table);
```

by doing so jtable is not being removed from container plz suggest me whats wrong in my   code

Comment: What is `ms`? What is `cp`.  You need to show more of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It sounds like your `Container` is using a layout manager which is deciding on how the internal frame should be displayed.  `JInternalFrame` is designed to work with containers that don't have a layout manager, most notably, the `JDesktopPane`.  For information check out [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)
2. It sounds like you actually want to use a dialog instead of a internal frame
3. Why are reconstructing the table from scratch?  Simply update the model.  Besides, you remove the table from `ms.cp` using `ms.cp.remove(table)` and then add it to something else, no wonder it never shows up.  See [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Comment: @adesh kumar or you have to add revalidate() & repaint() or to set Viewport view in the case that JTable is placed in JScrollPane